# Autocorrect email addresses

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm currently working on a PHP script to check and correct wrong typed email addresses.
If the input is: htomail.com, the script will change it to hotmail.com

I'm using the following code (for all possible typos):

```
$input = 'bill.gates@htomail.com';
$pattern = '/htomail.com/';
$replacement = 'hotmail.com';
$output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
echo $output;
```

etc.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to use a (sort of) spellchecker / autocorrect function to correct all possible typos.

Comment: And what would happen if I were to use my own `example@adamhaskell.net` domain? Would you try to autocorrect it to something?

Comment: Are you sure you want to go down that path? There are so many mail provider and so many domains out there and so many possible ways to spell them wrong.

Comment: Are you going to correct `ymail` to `gmail`?

Comment: You can do a dirty check using `similar_text` (documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php), but it is kind of a really difficult thing to determine programatically.

Comment: @DaveChen Think I need a 'library' of all (known) providers

Comment: Just send the email, and if they verify, then it's valid. I don't recommend correcting user input on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off telling the user that their email address appears invalid and allowing them to fix the mistake.

I use this code to make sure that the email is in a valid format and the domain name has a valid MX record.

```
    function validEmail($string){

        // correct format
        if (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            // valid domain name
            list($userName, $mailDomain) = explode("@", $string);
            if (checkdnsrr($mailDomain, "MX")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would highly recommend `filter_var` over some sort of home brew regex thing. Other than that, checking for an MX record is a good idea.

Comment: The code has been updated to reflect the suggestion made by @Mike

Answer (score 1):

You will be dealing with heuristics. You will be better of looking  for a library that already handles it for you. You pretty much have to check an entire database  to see if the word exists, check if it is spelled correctly, see if any other words would match the syntax, and let the user know which word is the correct one. Like in MS WORD spell check

Answer (score 1):

```
$wrong_email = "example@htomail.com";
ereg_replace(Array[], "@hotmail", $wrong_email);
```

The ereg_replace function will be very helpful if you could put all the frequent wrongs in an Array, so the function can look up for the wrongs using the array.

Answer (score 0):

Php have pspel bundled extension for that: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pspell.php
But I think you should for check domain use whois service.